# How do you send an email as part of the startup configure process?

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want my application to persist to if the email credentials were valid when first starting up and sending a startup email to a location as part of this test.

When I place email functions in startup or even SendGrid, if the credentials are valid there is no error, but no message sent. I can do it as part of a middleware filter and as part of a cache, but this would be my preference actually becoming a scoped service.

My email code works as part of a controller or service call, but even though it doesn't error in startup if the credentials are valid the email doesn't actually send.

*startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var emailStatus = new EmailStatus();

    try
        {
            _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Options.Support, "App STARTUP",
                   $"email success.");
            emailStatus.failed = false;
            //Set
        }
        catch (SmtpCommandException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            emailStatus.failed = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);

            // Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            _logger.LogError("Task Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException);
            _logger.LogError("Task StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            emailStatus.failed = false;
        }

      services.AddSingleton(emailStatus);
}
```

*EmailSender.cs*

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public EmailSender(AuthMessageSenderOptions options)
    {
        this.Options = options;

    }
    public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        return Execute(subject, message, email);
    }

    public async Task Execute(string subject, string message, string email)
    {
        if (Options.Service != "SendGrid")
        {
            var mailMessage = new MimeMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(email));
            mailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("noreply@email.com"));


            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
            {
                Text = message
            };
            // mailMessage.Body = message;
            //Be careful that the SmtpClient class is the one from Mailkit not the framework!
            using (var emailClient = new SmtpClient())
            {
                //The last parameter here is to use SSL (Which you should!)
                await emailClient.ConnectAsync(Options.Domain, Options.Port, true);

                //Remove any OAuth functionality as we won't be using it. 
                emailClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                emailClient.Authenticate(Options.SendGridUser, Options.SendGridKey);

                try
                {
                    await emailClient.SendAsync(mailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await emailClient.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await emailClient.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    throw ex;
                    // return BadRequest(new { message = "Email failed to send", error = ex.ToString() });
                    // Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
                }
                // emailClient.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            var client = new SendGridClient(Options.SendGridKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("noreply@email.com", "Do Not Reply"),
                Subject = subject,
                PlainTextContent = message,
                HtmlContent = message
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

            // Disable click tracking.
            // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
            msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

            await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out HostedService

Comment: You aren't awaiting your asynchronous call. `_emailSender.SendEmailAsync` needs to be awaited or waited on.

Comment: Also, never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You'll lose your stack trace. Just do `throw;`

Comment: You can’t await in startup

Comment: @lastlink any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `IHostedService`

Create a hosted service that will be started as part of the startup process

```
public class StartupEmailHostedService : IHostedService {
    private readonly IEmailSender emailSender;
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private EmailStatus emailStatus;

    public StartupEmailHostedService(IEmailSender emailSender, EmailStatus emailStatus, ILogger<StartupEmailHostedService> logger) {
        this.services = services;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.emailStatus = emailStatus;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        try {
            await emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Options.Support, "App STARTUP", $"email success.");
            emailStatus.failed = false;
        } catch (SmtpCommandException ex) {
            logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            emailStatus.failed = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            logger.LogError("Task Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException);
            logger.LogError("Task StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            emailStatus.failed = true;
        };
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Now make sure everything is registered with the service collection at start up.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...assuming other dependencies

    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    services.AddSingleton<EmailStatus>();
    services.AddHostedService<StartupEmailHostedService>();
}
```

When the hosted service is started, the email logic will be invoked along with the desired functionality.

Trying to do all those cross-cutting concerns in Startup is unnecessary and can potentially cause problems with the startup itself as it was simply meant to act as a bootstrapper and wire up what the application needs to perform its function.

Comment: so it is not possible to persist the result to a registerd scope? this is great that I can schedule background startup tasks this way, but is the emailStatus result available elsewhere where it's injected by di?

Comment: The status is a singleton, the same instance will be injected everywhere it is used as a dependency